# How to return data from a service not a HttpClient to component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular-services

I have this service and I need to return the products to components I don't use here the HttpClient or Observable as I don't need them

```
export class StoreDataProvider {

  private _wooData: any;

  constructor() {
    this._wooData = Woo({
      url: 'http://example.com/',
      consumerKey: 'key here',
      consumerSecret: 'key here',
      wpAPI: true,
      version: 'wc/v3'
    });
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    return this._wooData.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
      return res 
    });
  }

}
```

The code above returns the headers, not the products but if I console the products inside the service itself instead of return I get the products! the code be will like this:

```
export class StoreDataProvider {

  private _wooData: any;

  constructor() {
    this._wooData = Woo({
      url: 'http://example.com/',
      consumerKey: 'key here',
      consumerSecret: 'key here',
      wpAPI: true,
      version: 'wc/v3'
    });
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this._wooData.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
      console.log(res); 
    });
  }

}
```

The code in the component is just `console.log( this._wooService.getAllProducts() )` if I console log at the service

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking, but the answer is probably https://stackoverflow.com/q/6847697/3001761

Comment: I was asking how to return a response from a service that it's not coming from HttpClient module! 

And @SiddAjmera helped me with that! and I approved his answer you can check it out

Anyway thanks for coming over and interesting to helping me out with my question! ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of Appraoches of solving this:

### 1. **Using BehaviorSubject**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class StoreDataProvider {

  private _wooData: any;
  private wooData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public wooData$ = this.wooData.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this._wooData = Woo({...});
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this._wooData.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
      this.wooData.next(res);
    });
  }

}
```

And then you can use it in your Component like this:

```
constructor(private _wooService: WooService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._wooService.wooData$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  this._wooService.getAllProducts();
}
```

Note that initially you'll get null as we initialized the `BehaviorSubject` with `null`. But as soon as you call `getAllProducts` and receive the data, you're going to get your data.

### 2. **Using Promise.**

```
export class StoreDataProvider {

  private _wooData: any;

  constructor() {
    this._wooData = Woo({...});
  }

  getAllProducts(cb) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._wooData.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        else resolve(res);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

And then you can use it in your Component like this:

```
constructor(private _wooService: WooService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._wooService.getAllProducts()
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
}
```

### 3. **Using Callback**

```
export class StoreDataProvider {

  private _wooData: any;

  constructor() {
    this._wooData = Woo({...});
  }

  getAllProducts(cb) {
    this._wooData.get('products', (err, data, res) => {
      cb(res);
    });
  }

}
```

And then you can use it in your Component like this:

```
constructor(private _wooService: WooService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._wooService.getAllProducts((res) => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro for your answer it's really helped me ♥

Comment: @heshamshawky, I'm glad it did. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Can I ask you this I'm trying to learn ionic here! But I got confused by a weird problem that's when using the last angular version 6 or above I'm getting tons of errors when I use this lib ( woocommerce-api ) but if I use angular 5 ( Ionic 3 ) It's working great!!! I did a lot of research about that problem and I found that maybe the 'lib' woocomerce-api using some backend stuff code and that's not available anymore at angular from version +6! So is there a way I can use this module with angular 6 ( ionic 4 )? I'll be glad if you really helped me with this ♥